# What could cause very slow performance of single UPDATEs of a InnoDB table?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, innodb

I have a table in my web app for storing session data. It's performing badly, and I can't figure out why. Slow query log shows updating a row takes anything from 6 to 60 seconds.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
    `id` char(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `payload` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `last_activity` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `session_id_unique` (`id`) USING HASH
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

The PK is a `char(40`) which stores a unique session hash generated by the framework this project uses (Laravel).

(I'm aware of the redundancy of the PK and unique index, but I've tried all combinations and it doesn't have any impact on performance in my testing. This is the current state of it.)

The table is small - *fewer than 200 rows*.

A typical query from the slow query log looks like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO sessions (id, payload, last_activity) 
VALUES ('d195825ddefbc606e9087546d1254e9be97147eb', 
        'YTo1OntzOjY6Il90b2tlbiI7czo0MDoi...around 700 chars...oiMCI7fX0=', 
        1405679480) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    payload=VALUES(payload), last_activity=VALUES(last_activity);
```

I've done obvious things like checking the table for corruption. I've tried adding a dedicated PK column as an auto increment `int`, I've tried without a PK, without the unique index, swapping the `text` column for a very very large `varchar`, you name it.

I've tried switching the table to use MyISAM, and it's still slow.

Nothing I do seems to make any difference - the table performs very slowly.

My next thought was the query. This is generated by the framework, but I've tested hacking it out into a `UPDATE` with an `INSERT` if that fails. The slowness continued on the `UPDATE` statement.

I've read a lot of questions about slow `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements, but those usually related to bulk transactions. This is just one insert/update per user per request. The site is not remotely busy, and it's on its own VPS with plenty of resources.

What could be causing the slowness?

Comment: I don't think you need the `VALUES()` wrapping the column names on the last line of the query

Comment: Is anything else running on the system that might be locking the table?

Comment: Are there any triggers on the table?

Comment: Anything odd in the server's my.cnf?

Comment: e.g. you don't have the general log on?

Comment: No unusual settings, triggers or excessive logging. Just switched to use a file-based session storage instead of this table, and every other aspect of MySQL is flying along. Switch back, and I just had a 120sec load time from this query!

Comment: I have just had a brief play and set up a table as you described. Even inserting 1000 records (each with about 5k of data in the payload field) only took 4 seconds. Executing again to trigger the on duplicate key processing (updating nothing except the last_activity field) only took 0.3 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frustratingly, the answer is this case was a bad disk. One of the disks in the storage array had gone bad, and so writes were taking forever to complete. Simply that.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer but SE comment length is too damn short. So.

What happens if you run an identical INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE... statement directly on the command line? Please try with and without actual usage of the application. The application may be artificially slowing down this UPDATE (for example, in INNODB a transaction might be opened, but committed after a lot of time was consumed. You tested with MyISAM too which does not support transactions. Perhaps in that case an explicit LOCK could account for the same effect. If the framework uses this trick, I'm not sure, I don't know laravel) Try to benchmark to see if there is a concurrency effect.

Another question: is this a single server? Or is it a master that replicates to one or more slaves?

Apart from this question, a few observations:

- the values for id are hex strings. the column is unicode. this means 3*40 bytes are reserved while only 40 are utilized. This is a waste that will make things inefficient in general. It would be much better to use BINARY or ASCII as character encoding. Better yet, change the id column to BINARY data type and store the (unhexed) binary value
- A hash for a innodb PK table will scatter the data across pages. The idea to use a auto_incrment pk, or not explicitly declare a pk at all (this will cause innodb to create an autoincrement pk of its own internally) is a good idea.
- It looks like the payload is base64 encoded. Again the character encoding is specified to be unicode. Ascii or Binary (the character encoding, not the data type) is much more appropriate.
- the HASH keyword in the unique index on ID is meaningless. InnoDB does not implement HASH indexes. Unfortunately MySQL is perfectly silent about this (see http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=73326)

(while this list does offer angles for improvement it seems unlikely that the extreme slowness can be fixed with this. there must be something else going on)

Comment: Those are some interesting observations I had not know @roland, thanks.

Comment: Dropping the PK might be a good idea too as indexes arent good for inserts speed and you are probably not joining much to a session?

Comment: Personally I don't think you should create tables without PK. It is not a matter of joining or not, it is simply a basic principle that every table should have a PK. It's unfortunate that because of the implementation detail of InnoDB, auto-incrementing pk's perform better than hash or guids but that's how it is.

Comment: Those are all good points, thanks. I don't think any of that should result in 6, 60 or even 120 second query times though, do you?

Comment: @drewm, no, and as you might observe I pointed that out as well - With the exception of the app slowing things down. So my question remains: what happens if you bypass the app and go through the command line?

Comment: @RolandBouman Running the query directly from the mysql console is fast - no delays. Although the sessions table isn't currently being used by the application, as I've had to switch to file-based sessions to keep the site up.

Comment: @drewm Do you have some data on how many concurrent users would be accessing the table via the app? Can you run a benchmark (with say sysbench) while varying the number of concurrent users? This could help to figure out wheter you have to look at the database or the app.